# How to call model method in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

Hi I have to call model method in my controller and view. So for this I had done this:

category.rb

```
def self.category_list
    category = self.all.collect { |m| [m.name, m.id] }
    return category
end
```

products_controller.rb

```
def new
    @product = Product.new
    @category = Category.category_list
end
```

and in products/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product, action: "create", :html => {:class => "form-group"} do |f| %>
        <div class="fields">
          <%= f.label :model_name %>
          <%= f.text_field :model_name, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="fields">
          <%= f.label :model_number %>
          <%= f.text_field :model_number, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
        <div class="fields">
          <%= f.label :model_number %>
          <%= f.select(:category_id, @category, :prompt => 'Select') %>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div class="actions">
          <%= f.submit "Submit", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
        </div>
<% end %>
```

whem am giving this it gives me error `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError in ProductsController#new` 
Please guide how to solve this. Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `category_list` method should be simple oneliner: `pluck(:name, :id)`. In Ruby last line is what's returned from method, you don't need to specify `return` here

Comment: your `productscontroller#new` is not defining `@inventory` where is it initialized?

Comment: sorry its typo mistake

Comment: you are using `rails 3` ?

Comment: Check [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DangerousAttributeError.html) once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your model method writes this

```
def self.category_list
    Category.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
  end
```

and you are using field model_name so just because of this its giving an error of Dangerous attributes error so please change it to name hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

use this gem:

```
gem 'safe_attributes'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

also see [gem's documentation](https://github.com/bjones/safe_attributes) and you are done :)